# Retropie with Raspberry Pi 4 can't install dolphin

Tags: pi-4, retropie, arm, 64-bit

I have installed Retropie using the Pi Imager and when I try to install Dolphin in the experimental packages it gives me the error that it only works on a 64 bit OS, but according to this website,  [RetroPie platform support](https://retropie.org.uk/stats/pkgflags/), Dolphin should work on the armv8 32 bit as well.

Error:

```
Package flags: !all 64bit

Your rpi4 flags: rpi 32bit arm armv8 neon rpi gles gles3 gles31 mesa kms dispmanx
```

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but I think that the RetroPie page that you link to, could be out of date.

Although, admittedly, there seems to be conflicting reports and information.

Apparently 32-bit support was dropped a couple of years ago, although that seems to have been for Windows only. From [Obituary for 32-bit](https://dolphin-emu.org/blog/2014/05/19/obituary-32bit/):

> 32-bit ARM devices are not affected by this decision and will continue to be supported.

There is a thread, [dolphin install](https://retropie.org.uk/forum/topic/30174/dolphin-install), where someone has the *same issue* as you are experiencing on ARM and apparently you need to do a custom install to make it work, although what custom steps are actually required isn't specified:

> dolphin isn't available on standard builds of retropie due to its 64 bit requirements. Those who have gotten dolphin to run on custom installs on a pi 4 have reported that the performance is very bad.

Unless you really have to use a 32-bit OS, you are probably better off using a 64-bit OS.